# MySQL query involving SUM, JOIN and difference between the SUMs

Tags: mysql, join

I want to get the head to head results between user(alpha) and all his friends.

```
users
+--------+-------+
| userID | name  |
+--------+-------+
|      1 | alpha |
|      2 | beta  |
|      3 | gamma |
|      4 | delta |
+--------+-------+

relationships
+--------------+--------------+------------+
| user1_userID | user2_userID | friendship |
+--------------+--------------+------------+
|            1 |            2 |          1 |
|            1 |            3 |          1 |
|            1 |            4 |          0 |
+--------------+--------------+------------+

games
+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
| user1 | user2 | dollar_share_user1 | dollar_share_user2 |
+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     1 |     2 |                 50 |                350 |
|     3 |     1 |                100 |                200 |
|     1 |     3 |                150 |                150 |
|     3 |     1 |                100 |                300 |
+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+

ratings
+-------+-------+--------+
| user1 | user2 | rating |
+-------+-------+--------+
|     1 |     2 |      4 |
|     2 |     1 |      6 |
|     1 |     3 |      2 |
|     3 |     1 |      1 |
|     1 |     3 |      5 |
|     3 |     1 |      4 |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

And I need the output to be

```
output
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
| opponent_userID | opponent_name | delta_dollar_share | delta_ratings |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------+
|               2 | beta          |               -300 |           -2 |
|               3 | gamma         |                300 |            2 |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------+

where delta_dollar_share for 
 - beta: 50 - 350 = 300
 - gamma: (200+150+300) - (100+150+100) = 650 - 350 = 300
where delta_rating for
 - beta: 4 - 6 = -2
 - gamma: (2+5) - (1+4) = 2
```

I have been able to work out (with enough difficulty), the individual components of the output. But I am just not able to combine them all into one query.

```
-- get opponents
SELECT u1.userID, u1.name
FROM relationships r
    JOIN users u1
        ON (r.user2_userID = u1.userID)
WHERE (r.user1_userID = 1) AND (friendship = 1);


-- get delta_dollar_share for one opponent(gamma)
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN (user1 = 1) THEN SUM(dollar_share_user1)
        WHEN (user2 = 1) THEN SUM(dollar_share_user2)
    END) -
    (CASE
        WHEN (user1 = 3) THEN SUM(dollar_share_user1)
        WHEN (user2 = 3) THEN SUM(dollar_share_user2)
    END)
    AS delta_dollar_share
FROM games
WHERE
    ((user1 = 1) AND (user2 = 3)) OR 
    ((user1 = 3) AND (user2 = 1));


-- get delta_ratings for one opponent(gamma)
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN (user1 = 1) THEN rating END) - 
SUM(CASE WHEN (user1 = 3) THEN rating END) AS delta_ratings
FROM ratings
WHERE
    ((user1 = 1) AND (user2 = 3)) OR 
    ((user1 = 3) AND (user2 = 1));
```

Please help how do I combine all of this into a single query to get the needed output for all the opponents ? [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fd7b/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. I've correlated your 2nd and 3rd queries off the first one. I also changed the expressions to use a single sum that switches the sign of the values as appropriate.

```
SELECT
    u.userID, u.name,
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(
            (gm.dollar_share_user1 - gm.dollar_share_user2) *        
            CASE when gm.user1 = r.user1_userID then 1 else -1 end
        )
    FROM games gm
    WHERE
            gm.user1 = r.user1_userID AND gm.user2 = r.user2_userID
        OR  gm.user1 = r.user2_userID AND gm.user2 = r.user1_userID
    ) AS delta_dollar_share,
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(rating * CASE when rt.user1 = r.user1_userID then 1 else -1 end)
    FROM ratings rt
    WHERE
            rt.user1 = r.user1_userID AND rt.user2 = r.user2_userID
        OR  rt.user1 = r.user2_userID AND rt.user2 = r.user1_userID
    ) AS delta_ratings
FROM
    relationships r INNER JOIN users u
        ON r.user2_userID = u.userID
WHERE
    r.user1_userID = ? AND r.friendship = 1; /* ? = 1 in your example */
```

Working sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fd7b/16

You're really just summing up all the dollar share and ratings values except that you count them as positive when the user id corresponds to user 1 while the values for the other user get deducted. So for dollar share one of them is always positive while the other is negative which is why it's a difference operation inside the parentheses. Ultimately it's still all addition so a single `sum()` is sufficient but you just need to flip the signs according to the result of the `case` expression.

I inserted the extra calculations as subqueries that are linked up (correlated) to the outer query with `r.user1_userID` and `r.user2_userID`.

Comment: @Jorge Basically I screwed up in adding aliases. I think it works now.

Comment: This looks elegant and it works. But I am a bit dense to follow it. Can you please elaborate a little on what is happening (e.g. rating*CASE). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Jorge for adding the link to the fiddle. I was just going back to do it myself!

Comment: I was mentally stuck with the idea that `SUM` can be done "only at the end" as an aggregation.  This is a revelation. Thanks a bunch.